# Why Spring data JpaRepository method name complement does not work with Class type parameter?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a class like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Foo implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private String id;
    private Boolean deleted = Boolean.FALSE;
    private Boolean active = Boolean.TRUE;
...

}
```

and a repository like this:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface FooRepository<F extends Foo> extends JpaRepository<F, String> {

}
```

**now the problem:**
when I use class level type parameters(generics) like above, intellij does not make or complete spring-data`s named query but if I remove the generics like below then I can write named queries in the repository interface

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, String> {

        Integer countAllByActive(boolean flag);
}
```

anybody knows why and is there any solution?

Comment: What exactly is it you are trying to do here?

Comment: I want to have **FooRepository** with Type **pamater <F>** as a **Jparepository** features such as method queries.

Comment: Please clarify the problem - either IDEA doesn't do what you expect or the application produces error when you invoke `countAllByActive` method from generic repository class?

Comment: yes, if you made your named Query by yourself, there is no error but IDE doesn't understand generic in an interface that extends JpaRepository so the auto compliment doesn't work.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue.  It is reproducible as described in the issue above. IntelliJ stops suggesting autocompletion for JPA-Methods at the moment you are adding a generic Type. So `public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Object, String>` works, but `interface FooRepository<F> extends JpaRepository<Object, String>`  does not!